# Method traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) of my UIView subclass not called when rotating

Tags: ios

The document of UITraitEnvironment says:

> This method is called automatically when the current trait collection
>   changes. Overriding this method provides you with a way to customize
>   behavior when the trait collection associated with the view changes.
>   If you do not override this method, no special behavior is performed.

But when I rotate simulator this method in my UIView subclass is not called.

Comment: you are probably running on iOS 7

Comment: I found that if the view is added to the `UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow` it won't get called. In case this applies to others.

Answer (score 4):

A UIView alone has never been able to respond to rotation changes. You'll need to reconfigure views for a current orientation/size from their containing view controller.

If you are on iPad, even on iOS 8, the trait collection does not change due to rotation; you will still be in H:Regular, V:Regular. 
You will want to override:

`func viewWillTransitionToSize(_ size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)`

to respond to the view controller's size changing due to rotation. (Make sure to call super!)

You can divine the "orientation" of the view controller by comparing the size's width to height (although modern iOS programming would encourage you to stop thinking in terms of orientation):

`let isPortrait = size.height > size.width`